# Prove that OLS residuals have 0 expectation even when the linear model is false

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, residuals, law-of-large-numbers

For the sake of this question, I will consider a linear model as a statistical model such that $\mathbb{E}[y|\mathbf{x}]=\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\beta}$. I know that usually some more assumptions go in the definition of the linear model. However, the other properties are mostly needed for OLS **estimation** of the linear model, and all of them can be relaxed (see the excellent post by Glen_b [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/55114/58675)).

In my answer to the question

[Estimating error - residuals vs. fitted values plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282042/estimating-error-residuals-vs-fitted-values-plot/282409#282409)

I stated that, even when $\mathbb{E}[y|\mathbf{x}]\neq\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\beta}$, the OLS residuals have expectation 0 because of the Law of Large Numbers. However, this might be wrong:   if we have a random sample $S=\{(y_i,\mathbf{x}_i)\}_{i=1}^n$, then we know that
 $$\sum_{i=1}^ne_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}\mathbf{x}_i)=0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

whatever the sample size (in other words, residuals are not independent). Now, 
Let $e$ denote the random variable whose realizations are the $e_i$. The Law of Large Numbers would tell you that

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ne_i}{n}=0 \ \ \forall n\rightarrow\mathbb{E}[e]=0$$

**if** the residuals were independent, but they aren't. However, property $\ref{1}$ is true because of the definitions of the OLS estimator, thus the sample mean of the residuals is always zero, even when the linear model is "false", i.e., when $\mathbb{E}[y|\mathbf{x}]\neq\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\beta}$. My question is: is $\mathbb{E}[e]=0$ true, even when $\mathbb{E}[y|\mathbf{x}]\neq\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\beta}$? Simulations seem to indicate that this is indeed the case.

I tried to prove it rigorously by linear algebra and rules of expectation, but I got stuck pretty soon:

$$e=y-(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^Ty\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[e|X]=\mathbb{E}[y|X]-(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbb{E}[y|X]$$

If I knew that $\mathbb{E}[y|\mathbf{x}]=\mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\beta}$, then from the above I would immediately get $\mathbb{E}[e|X]=0$, which implies  $\mathbb{E}[e]=0$ by the law of iterated expectations. But I can't assume that. Suggestions?

---

PS yes, I **know** that using lower-case for both random variables and their realizations is horrible, but if I use upper-case for the RV $\mathbf{X}$, then I don't know what symbol I to use for the design matrix.

Comment: You define the $e_i$ as the residuals with respect to the OLS solution. Obviously their sum is always zero: that's a mathematical property of the solution. But if the model is not what you suppose, then isn't it equally obvious that the expectation of any individual $e_i$ could be any number whatsoever? For instance, let $x_1$ be the mean of the regressors of all the other data points. Suppose the model is correct for all the other $x_i,$ $i\ne 1$, but $E(y_1)=x_1\beta+A$ for some constant $A\ne 0$. You can easily compute that this makes $E(e_1)=A/n\ne 0$. What, then, are you trying to ask?

Comment: @whuber not sure what $x_1$ is. Is it the mean of the regressors vector? i.e.,   $x_1=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}]=(\mu_{x_1},\dots,\mu_p)$ where $p$ is the number of regressors.

Comment: No, it's the mean of all the other regressors: they aren't (or don't have to be) considered as stochastic.  Why not do a calculation with a very simple example?  Try the model $(0,\beta_0+\epsilon_1),(-1,\beta_0-\beta_1+\epsilon_2),(1,\beta_0+\beta_1+\epsilon_3)$ fit *via* OLS, for instance. Compare two situations, both with independent errors $\epsilon_i$ and homogeneous variances. In the usual situation they all have zero means.  In the "wrong model" alternative, suppose $\epsilon_1$ has a mean of $A$ but you are still computing the OLS estimator.  It's easy to figure out $\mathbb{E}(e_1)$.

Comment: @whuber ok, I think I understood your setting. I will try the exercise and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed a typographical error in my previous comment, in order to make all three of the $\epsilon_i$ distinct.  It's intended to be the usual OLS setting with three data points, of which the first has its x-value equal to the mean of the other two x-values. By making that common mean zero, the matrix $X^\prime X=\pmatrix{3&0\\0&2}$ is easily inverted, making all your calculations simple.